# Backbone.js collection.models not showing, but there

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a view that's doing a fetch() to a collection and returning some models from the server.

```
ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection = new ProductCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({data: {limit : this.options.limit}});

        console.log(this.collection);

        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {

        var template = _.template( $("#product-template").html(), this );
        $(this.el).html( template );
        return this;
    }
});
```

In the console.log above, I see the object like this:

```
products.view.js:13
d
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
length: 7
models: Array[7]
__proto__: x
```

The `models` is there, but when I do `console.log(this.collection.models)` it shows just `[]`, inside the models, is an array of objects like this:

```
models: Array[7]
0: d
1: d
2: d
3: d
4: d
5: d
6: d
```

Each of these have `attributes` with the values that were returned.

Any idea why the models won't show when I use `this.collection.models` or using `get()` doesn't work either.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you write that `console.log(this.collection.models)`? I mean the one that gives you an empty array as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general `this.collection.fetch({data: {limit : this.options.limit}})` is an asynchronous operation, so you next line is not necessarily going to print the correct content of the `collection`.

Instead you should use `success` and `error` callbacks the `fetch` method provides as part of its `options` parameter (or listen to collection's `change` event), like so:

```
this.collection.fetch(
    { 
        data: { limit : this.options.limit },
        success : function(collection, rawresponse) { 
            // do something with the data, like calling render 
        }
    }
);
```

For completness sake:

```
this.collection.on('change', function(){ // some handling of the data };
this.collection.fetch();
```

is the event-based method.

Comment: I would emphasize that listening for change event is a way to go. Collection should not handle view rendering.

Comment: It may, however, handle some data manipulation. I do prefer event- based development, so no argument from me.

Comment: @ZenMaster I did it within the callback but it still didn't display the models when I do `this.collection.models` - could it be related to it showing as an array (`Array[7]`) instead of an Object?

Comment: It seems to me that the output is OK then. Can you access any of the items of the array and its properties?

Comment: Yeah, I can access them directly, but not using collection.models, so the model doesn't recognize the data