# How do I iterate a Backbone Firebase Collection?

Tags: backbone.js, firebase, backfire

I currently started using `Firebase` as my backend solution for persistance.

I found it easy to create new objects and persist it to Firebase with Backfire with a simple

```
collection.add(obj)
```

The issue comes when I try to get a Firebase collection from the server. 
For example when i try

```
console.log(collection);
```

I get this output:

```
=> {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _events: Object, constructor: function…}
```

Which result in an empty models array

```
console.log(collection.models);
=> []
```

After some searching, I figured out that Backbone Collections aren't yet loaded at the time I try to log it to the console ([see this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051685/backbone-js-collection-models-not-showing-but-there)).

I also tried using

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Todo,
  firebase: new Backbone.Firebase("https://<your-namespace>.firebaseio.com")
});
```

To `explicitly` call `fetch` from the server and use success callback with no success either.

My question is: **How can I get the Firebase Collection and populate the DOM from it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Backbone.Firebase.Collection.add`, it does not get added to the collection synchronously. Rather, it sends the request to Firebase and then waits for the return event. [See the code here](https://github.com/firebase/backfire/blob/gh-pages/backbone-firebase.js#L211)

Thus, if you immediately try to read the collection, you will see zero elements. However, if you try something like this:

```
collection.once('add', function() { console.log(collection.length); });
```

You'll see the element you have added.

Remember that we're dealing with real-time data here, so when you want to populate the DOM, you shouldn't think in terms of a single transaction, but instead rely on events and take everything as you get it (in real time).

So to populate the DOM, do something like this in your view:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.rowAdded);
   },

   rowAdded: function(m) {
      /* use `m` here to create your new DOM element */
   }
});
```

Additionally, you'll probably want to check out a nice binding library like [ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) to help you deal with the constantly changing DOM, so you don't have to re-invent any wheels.

Comment: Very nice answer @Kato, thank you. It's more clear now. But i don't understand when an `add` events is fired. Also what the argument `m` represents? And how can i use it?

Comment: The add event is fired whenever an element is added to the collection. Which occurs after Firebase delivers new records ([see here](https://github.com/firebase/backfire/blob/gh-pages/backbone-firebase.js#L268)). All of the collection events pass the affected Backbone.Model (i.e. `m`) when the callback is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to use a `Backbone.Firebase.Collection` and not a `Backbone.Collection` which will tell you that your calls to `fetch` or `sync` are silently ignored.

Also, `Backbone.Firebase`'s got a `read` and a `readall` methods that should get you started. It seems `Backbone.Firebase.Collection` doesn't inherit this method, but I'm not sure though.

**Edit:**
As **Kato** stated in his comment, it seems you don't have to do anything. Just use `Backbone.Backfire.Collection` and `Backbone.Backfire.Model`.

Comment: The sync is implicit with Backbone.Firebase.Collection -- no need for a read or readall; it happens immediately.

Comment: @Kato thought so from the doc, but wasnt sure as I couldnt find it in Backfire's code. Now realizing I was searching in the wrong place as it's surely in Firebase's code.

Comment: The read is done [via the `child_added` call here](https://github.com/firebase/backfire/blob/gh-pages/backbone-firebase.js#L183), which automagically and immediately fetches all the existing records.